# Unable to save or load my code in the IBM Swift Sandbox

Tags: swift, ibm-swift-sandbox

Whenever I attempt to Save Code of mine, the Sandbox gets stuck on "Saving Snapshot" with the little dots jiggling below.

Also, when I attempt to Load Code that is something other than the sample code tab, it just says "Loading".

I've tried various browsers, and disabling any adblock or Ghostery-type utilities, without any success.

It does seem to 'Autosave' what I am working on, but that's about it and I can't even give the code a save name.

Are you others experiencing this situation also, with the IBM Swift Sandbox?

https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/

Comment: It seems that our database is having some issues. We're taking a look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that our database server has gone down, since we can't ping it. We don't have the appropriate error checking in place at the moment, but we're going to be updating the code so that we handle these situations a bit more gracefully, instead of just hanging forever on a load/save dialogue. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

EDIT: our database server is back up, and we've also pushed a code change so those database requests will time out and fail more gracefully.

Comment: Glad to be of some help! Please let us know when the Sandbox is back in normal operation?

Comment: @Tim the servers are back up!

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your weekend work, and for the cool Swift Sandbox! IBM rocks!

Comment: @Tim no problem! We're glad you're enjoying it, we're always happy to hear positive feedback from our users!

Comment: Actually there is still a problem - when I attempt to save code, it gives me "Error communicating with database. Snapshot not saved."

Comment: @Tim we're still having some server issues at the moment, but we're trying to mitigate them. At the least we managed to add a new error message so the Sandbox no longer hangs forever on a loading/saving message. Hopefully full snapshot functionality should be restored across all users in a few minutes.